# How many times, are they multiples?

Tags: code-golf, math, division

You are given three parameters: start(int), end(int) and list(of int);

Make a function that returns the amount of times all the numbers between **start** and **end** are multiples of the elements in the **list**.
example:

```
start = 15; end = 18; list = [2, 4, 3];
15 => 1 (is multiple of 3)
16 => 2 (is multiple of 2 and 4)
17 => 0
18 => 2 (is multiple of 2 and 3)
result = 5
```

The function should accept two positive integer numbers and an array of integers as parameters, returning the total integer number. Assume that start is less <= end.

examples:

```
Multiple(1, 10, [1, 2]); => 15
Multiple(1, 800, [7, 8]); => 214
Multiple(301, 5000,[13, 5]); => 1301
```

The shortest solution is the victor!!! May he odds be ever in your favor...

Comment: Nice challenge! Presumably the winning criterion is shortest code? In which case you should say so explicitly, and add the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: Can we assume that `start` will always be less than `end`?

Comment: You say integers. So `start`, `end` or the elements in `list` may be non-positive?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was lacking that in the problem.

Comment: I'd like to ask a question (as I'm really new in this channel), how do I decide the winner? since each language has it's own limitations... Or is it simply a personal preference?

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
ŸÑ˜åO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6I7DE0/PObzU//9/YwNDLlMDAwOuaENjHdNYAA)

---

#### Explanation

```
Ÿ       - the numbers between start and end 
 Ñ      - get their divisors
  ˜     - deep flatten this list
   å    - find the instances of the elements in the list in these divisors
    O   - Sum this
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 33 bytes

```hs
(a#b)x=sum[1|0<-mod<$>[a..b]<*>x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNROUmzwra4NDfasMbARjc3P8VGxS46UU8vKdZGy64i9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKGoamyoYVmtJGOiY5x7H8A)

Explanation:

```hs
(a#b)x                            --take two values a and b and the list x
                      [a..b]      --generate the range a, a+1, ... , b
                mod<$>[a..b]      --partially apply "mod" to each entry of the list
                mod<$>[a..b]<*>x  --apply the partially applied functions to all values of the list x
          [1|0<-mod<$>[a..b]<*>x] --generate a new list with a one for every zero in the previously computed list
(a#b)x=sum[1|0<-mod<$>[a..b]<*>x] --sum it all up
```

Comment: Nice method. I found a [variant that ties](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yba4NFcvN7FAwyBOU08jNz/FRsUuOlFPLynWRstO839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKGoamyoYVmtJGOiY5x7H8A) and tried to shorten it point-free but could [tie at best](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P1E5yba4NFdPQ0PDIE5TT1MvNz/FRsUuOlFPLynWRstO839uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCioKGoamyoYVmtJGOiY5x7H8A) -- maybe you have a better idea.

Comment: @xnor I've also tried to get rid of the `x`, but without success, the `(0^)` trick is neat, please consider posting it as an own answer! (So far I have had no success in golfing your suggestions further.)

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
(a,x,y)=>a.map(n=>t+=y/n-(~-x/n|0)|0,t=0)&&t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwFATQfU/xV5LQH/OjDXUTL1K6CFZLiyZSQ1GQXj1NEbpwNgPDY572bafm9RiDcP7Wxs5EZnHGhZva5oMdmTN1OJpFOsE@YpZuJb4SBkM8y0JsvJt83@a9v7OOXRRCcUVIpYhz2CIlKH3YyTNCtcmK/jTJQp32VJUIOtmSkta08d9pGuIX)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda a,x,y:sum(y/i-~-x/i for i in a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxBCoMwFATQfU8x4CaBLyaxoVLwJG0XKSU0UKOoBbPx6umHgJ3NMPCYKa3vMZrs@3v@uOH5cnC0Ubou30GkJtR7vTUBfpwRECKczNMc4iq8uGmCeRC4tJISJRW0PR3kQugK6dRhKhh9/hvdEiyjVjGzqji@4Z1/)

\$ \sum _{i \in list} \lfloor \frac{end}{i} \rfloor - \lfloor \frac{start-1}{i} \rfloor \$

The answer seems trivial and naive. So am I misunderstand something?

Comment: Your Python answer is right -- I was going to post the same. Congrats on figuring out the simplification. I'm disappointed nobody else had found the floor-division idea earlier, at least on my quick glance of the answers.

Comment: @xnor the formula comes up with my mind just after I read the question. But since the question is posted ~1d ago (and no one using it), I can't quite believe it could be correct. After posting the JavaScript version, I realized that by using Python I could save many bytes..

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 21 bytes

```perl6
{sum $^a..$^b X%%@^c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0V0ElLlFPTyUuSSFCVdUhLrn2vzVXcWKlQpqGoY6hgU60oY5RrCZCyMIAKGauY4EQMzYw1FEwNQCJGxrrmAIl/gMA)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                   }   # Anonymous codeblock returning
 sum                    # The sum of
     $^a..$^b           # How many numbers in the range a to b
              X%%       # Are divisible by any of
                 @^c    # The third parameter
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:i\~z
```

Inputs are a cell array containing the `start` and `end` values,  and then a column vector defining `list`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yozpq7q//9qQ1MFQ4tarmgjawUTawXjWAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yozpq7q//9qQ1MdBUOLWq5oI2sFE2sF41gA).

#### Explanation

```
:    % Range, with implicit input: cell array {start, end}. This gives the range
     % from start to end
i    % Input: list of numbers in the form of a column vector
\    % Modulo, with boradcast. This gives a matrix with each number in the range
     % modulo each number in the list
~    % Logical negation 
z    % Number of nonzero entries. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 54 bytes

```
lambda s,e,L:sum(n%l<1for n in range(s,e+1)for l in L)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VclBDsIgEIXhfU/BxgTixDDFRmL0Br1B46IqVRIYGqCLnh7pxuhL3ub75zW/A6li/RxiZmlNTf0hmRzNY4nJBnLW28xR1okyXd3o78@RJTDQn9PiOe3cBacQGTFLLI70MrzWPYoN3Ya9KHO0lPnEsQPUMLRwBHUTovk6oIQBof1HLaueQP@qkgid3AIq6GopHw)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
function(a,b,l)sum(b%/%l-(a-1)%/%l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmD7P600L7kkMz9PI1EnSSdHs7g0VyNJVV81R1cjUddQE8TS/J@mYaijYGgAxFZGmlxgnoUBkGtuZQHiGhsABUwNQCLJGobGQLam5n8A)

Implementation of [tsh's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196599/67312) by [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe). 3 bytes shorter than the previous version:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> 38 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to Nick Kennedy and Xi'an.

```r
function(a,b,l)sum(!outer(a:b,l,`%%`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmD7P600L7kkMz9PI1EnSSdHs7g0V0Mxv7QktUgj0QoooJOgqpqgqfk/TcNQR8HQAIitjDS5wDwLAyDX3MoCxDU2AAqYGoBEkjUMjYFsoB4A)

Boils down to summing the values of `!(x %% y)` for `x` in `a:b` and `y` in `l` (`%%` is \$mod\$ in R, so `x %% y == 0` iff `x` is a multiple of `y`).

Comment: Though it removes your first use of `Negate`, https://tio.run/##K/qfpmD7P600L7kkMz9PI1EnSSdHs7g0V0Mxv7QktUgj0QoooJOgqpqgqfk/TcNQR8HQAIitjDS5wDwLAyDX3MoCxDU2AAqYGoBEkjUMjYFsoB4A is shorter.

Comment: @NickKennedy Yes, of course, thanks! Xian just told me as much… Don't know why I didn't think of it! I guess I was too eager to use `Negate`.

Comment: [35](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmD7P600L7kkMz9PI1EnSSdHs7g0VyNJVV81R1cjUddQE8TS/J@mYaijYGgAxFZGmlxgnoUBkGtuZQHiGhsABUwNQCLJGobGQLam5n8A) using [tsh's method.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196599/67312)

Answer (score 5):

## APL+WIN, <s>20</s> 15 bytes

5 bytes saved thanks to Adam.

Prompts for end integer, start integer and then list:

```
+/,0=⎕∘.|⎕↓0,⍳⎕
```

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv7a@joEtUOxRxwy9GhDdNtlA51HvZiDzP1DB/zQuQwsuQ1MuIwUTBWMuIM@Ay5DLUMEIyLQwALHNFSyAbFMDIMfYAChlrGAKAA)

Could be reduced to 9 bytes if we could enter two lists and not have to generate the first:

```
+/,0=⎕∘.|⎕
```

Comment: ``+/+/`` → ``+/,``

Comment: `s+⍳1+⎕-s←⎕` → `⎕↓0,⍳⎕`

Answer (score 5):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>113</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> <s>108</s> <s>106</s> <s>100</s> <s>93</s> <s>99</s> <s>91</s> 89 bytes

```cpp
using I=int;I s;void f(I a,I b,I*l,I z,I&s){for(s=0;a<=b;++a)for(I i=z;i--;)s+=a%l[i]<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc9Ba4MwGMbxu5/igbGhM0LUyqQxu@czSA@p2hJIYzG6Q8XP7pIquw22S0L@h9/7prnfk0ZLc13XySpzheDKjEzAsq9etbiEApIInIl41@5@EPFmo/nSD6HllMmKn1kcy8gHAcUfTCUJi2zM5auu1alK2bK@KNPoqe1Qqd6OQydvn4GbgptUJowwB/AvXZ845ozgQJAvLHCz04IgLQm0KwQ2ctGO7fHY9NOIqoJ9Hr50ptUs2KG0PsFRKUG2O46hjvHlH062OR8E5Y9TUg9lf4Q2J9/3cX8oNiinjiro08p/s/weQzdOgwFlwbJ@Aw)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO!!!
Saved <s>6</s> 13 bytes thanks to @bznein!!!
<s>Added 6</s> Saved 8 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO (and now it's playing by the rules)!!!

Comment: You can use #import<vector> to save 1

Comment: @AZTECCO Thanks, didn't know about `#import`. :-)

Comment: #include is standard.. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/172264/7699953 btw you can save 2 by using  s+=a%i<1; instead of s+=a%i?0:1;

Comment: @AZTECCO Ah, good to see Microsoft doing something useful for the code-golfing community. Thanks for the -2! :-)

Comment: I am not that familiat to codegolf rules, but is it mandatory to use vector? std::set would save 6 bytes. If we are to allow duplicated entries, std::list is still 102 bytes

Comment: @bznein Good point! No, vector isn't mandatory. It's more usual to allow you to input and output as suits you best. Thanks! :-)

Comment: If we can choose also output as we wish, can we use int&s as parameter to the function? `#import<set>
void f(int a,int b,std::set<int>l,int&s){for(;a<=b;++a)for(int i:l)s+=a%i<1;}` is 90 bytes.

This will however require us to set s to 0 before calling the function, which might not follow the rules, but even initializing s inside the function leads to 94 bytes: 
`#import<set>
void f(int a,int b,std::set<int>l,int&s){s=0;for(;a<=b;++a)for(int i:l)s+=a%i<1;}`

Comment: @bznein Ingenious! Totally valid and oft used way to return data from a C++ function, so I'm guessing it's ok?

Comment: It's valid : https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4942/84844

Comment: @AZTECCO Thanks for the clarification, that's then another way to snip the lettery `return`!

Comment: Yes, anyway I'm not sure but I think you have to include declaration of s ''int s;'' in the bytecount

Comment: Sounds like the right thing to do, otherwise you could initialise it outside the byte count too. Still shorter! :-)

Comment: Suggestion : if you don't need to use a particular algorithm or many containers, it's better to use plain arrays most of the times. [85+ 6??](https://tio.run/##lY/NboMwEITv@xQrVa34MQqGoKIY@iKIg8NPZMkxEYYegnh2akPUU5HoZWyPdz/NVI9HUEmubsvy3YkaW0eoATmxerXqyfX@tPqh3antekfnIeNZfmW@z11r2AmRP5kIAuZqP@fvshBlRtm8vAlVybFuMBOdHvqG37/Ajt@5UI6LE6B9yaLMcYoIngnGM9tMbc7WoQlBmhKU5oegdo2ph/pyqbpxwCxDvYp1GlVLBi8gLUo0SEowmjeOwYQGY51/cKKN80kw/eWkoQVFB0EbJ37lMR2SDRSHBpWEKyveY5kcgH0zjL3CkMEMJw9Q/t3sUBi50@bY8n6DnfQzJEATiOgZqBkH8E7LDw "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice! Was using a standard container for the `for (int i:l)` but this is shorter! :-)

Comment: @AZTECCO So many `int`s! Managed to save 2 bytes using `using`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 41 bytes

```ruby
->a,e,l{l.sum{|x|(a..e).count{|r|r%x<1}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ1UnpzpHr7g0t7qmokYjUU8vVVMvOb80r6S6pqimSLXCxrC2tvZ/gUJatKGOoYEOkDSKjf0PAA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

Takes input as `(list, start)(end)`.

```javascript
(a,x,s=0)=>g=y=>y<x?s:g(y-1,a.map(c=>y%c||s++))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XczRCoIwGIbh865iJ8GGv7pfG0k0u5DoYCwdhjlpEQ6897UYdOB3@PLwPdRHOf0a5nc@2XsXehmoggWc5Ey2RnrZ@vNycSdDfY6giqeaqY5xr9fVZRljQdvJ2bErRmtoT68IpLoBQUaRM0bSypKg2G3kEUiTZMP/NMoKD1uKNRARbc2jFjzx32kM4Qs)

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes

```
{+//~z!\:x_!1+y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcc7DoAgEAXAqyyVEKLsA4mEvYqJHQ2FrZ/o1ZHYzdRxr62VfFvn3kut@dgU7Pm0Mg1aIwqSeJopGNEQsID8z8QsC6XuwJDIvQgUjWkf)

### Explanation:

```
{+//~z!\:x_!1+y} - function with 3 arguments [x;y;z] <- (start; end; list)
           !1+y  - a list 0 to end (inclusive)
         x_      - drop the first start numbers
     z!\:        - find the modulo of each number in the range start..end with each of list
    ~            - negate (0 becomes 1, non-zero becomes 0)
 +//             - reduce by addition and converge (repeat until result stops changing)
```

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
1#.1#.0=[|/(}.i.,])/@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcixCsIwFEDRPV9x0aEWyut7xmAoBPofpZMY1MWha/vtMUjgTOdT8pYEZUKLnaXStOzj5ZC3DGs/zmvp3UnocpKOgWMib849H68vXLnhyVjAYjurWwfTFnfiP6K2MU@o49UIqlp@)

### Explanation:

The verbs (functions) in [J](http://jsoftware.com/) can take one (right) or two (left and right) arguments. The left argument is the `list`, the right one - a list of the `start` and `end` numbers.

```
           (       )/@     insert the verb in () between the elements of
                      ]    the right argument (start and end)
                 ,         append
               i.          a list 0..end-1
                  ]        to the right argument (end)
             }.            drop start elements
          |/               insert modulo verb between the above list and 
         [                 the left argument (the list)
       0=                  compare each with 0
    1#.                    sum by base 1 conversion 
 1#.                       sum by base 1 conversion 
                           (we do it twice, because the result of |/ is a table)
```

Comment: Some explanation would be good

Comment: @AZTECCO I added an explanation of the `K` answer. I'm going to add the `J` one soon.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,m,l:m/n and sum(n%i<1for i in l)+f(n+1,m,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBDoIwEIXhvaeYjUkbJtoBicToSQgLFBonoVPSlgWnr7Ax@pJ/8@XNa3p7KTO72YcEcY2HrVMcUxhfS4jsZWLHSZHZprN9TL17Dj0IOpxu7izQywBxcUqOfCfrAzCwwKQLq6Sg/abzHFgSWEU1UoNtiResOn34MpLBlrD8s8ZseMXmBytDWJvdqcK60/kD)

Comment: Cool trick using the recursion and division!

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program, prompting for **end**, **start**, **list**, from stdin.

```apl
≢⍸=⎕|\⎕…⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jzkWPenfYPuqbWhMDJB41LAOSIKn/CmBQwGVowWVoymWkYKJgzAUX4zI04DJUMEISsDAw4DJXsICLGBsYcpkaAAUNjRVMAQ)

`⎕` prompt for **end**

`⎕…` prompt for **start** and generate progression vector

`⎕|\` prompt for **list* and make division remainder table

`=` Boolean mask indicating where equal to zero

`⍸` get the indices of the Trues

`≢` tally them

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 40 bytes

```bash
eval set !\$[{$1..$2}%{$3}]+;echo $[$*0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7UsMUehOLVEQTFGJbpaxVBPT8WoVrVaxbg2Vts6NTkjX0ElWkXLIPb////GBob/TQ0MDP4bGuuYAgA)

Answer (score 3):

## APL(NARS), chars 13, bytes 26

```
{+/∊0=⍺∣../⍵}
```

⍺ it is the list of divisors, ⍵ it is the range. Test:

```
  1 2{+/∊0=⍺∣../⍵}1 10
15
  7 8{+/∊0=⍺∣../⍵}1 800
214
  13 5{+/∊0=⍺∣../⍵}301 5000
1301
  13 5 3 11{+/∊0=⍺∣../⍵}301 5000
3294
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
r/ḍ@€FS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79I/@GOXodHTWvcgv///29oqmNo8d9Ix0THGAA)

A dyadic link taking a list of `[start, end]` as the left argument and the list of possible divisors as the right argument. Returns an integer indicating the total number of possible divisions.

Comment: Nice answer! My version was also [a 7 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79I9VHTmkeNW90OrQn@//@/oel/Q4v/0UY6JjrGsQA) (tryadic link).

Answer (score 2):

## Java (JDK), <s>115</s> 67 bytes

```java
(s,e,d)->{int t=0;for(;s<=e;s++)for(int j:d)t+=s%j<1?1:0;return t;}
```

*48 bytes saved thanks to Olivier*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7BasMwDIbvfQpdBjZxg7OsrNRN@wQ59Th28BKnOEucYisdI@TZMzsYxgZjFwn90ie@Vt7ltq3fl9v41ukKqk46B6XUBqYNgEOJPtUGlW1kpaBcYwgJNCRUx9ZBre3lFWoq/MX8DZfQQwELcUyxmm5PUzjHgotmsES4Y6GESxIaprBpDzXFpHAP7TE7ZwcurMLRGkAxL@FzFI3P74Ouofe65IJWm6sXkPbqaNS8fDpUfTqMmN78GjtD@rQh2Y5Btmdg1Ee0nh4ZPDHIZ7rq/00y2HP@g3z20X9Yzj2447/ILPdhROfNvHwB)

First time golfing in Java, so this is a new experience for me.

Comment: Well, you can declare lambda methods: `(s,e,d)->{...}`. Also, you can remove spaces and probably [use a few golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6671/16236). [Here's my take](https://tio.run/##hY7BasMwDIbvfQpdBjZxg7OsrNRN@wQ59Th28BKnOEucYisdI@TZMzsYxgZjFwn90ie@Vt7ltq3fl9v41ukKqk46B6XUBqYNgEOJPtUGlW1kpaBcYwgJNCRUx9ZBre3lFWoq/MX8DZfQQwELcUyxmm5PUzjHgotmsES4Y6GESxIaprBpDzXFpHAP7TE7ZwcurMLRGkAxL@FzFI3P74Ouofe65IJWm6sXkPbqaNS8fDpUfTqMmN78GjtD@rQh2Y5Btmdg1Ee0nh4ZPDHIZ7rq/00y2HP@g3z20X9Yzj2447/ILPdhROfNvHwB) on golfing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 59 bytes

```
procedure f(a,b,l)
n:=0
(a to b)%!l<1&n+:=1&\z
return n
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc5BCsMgEIXhvaewiwals3BipRKak6RdmMSAkIxFDIVePo27kr7tx4M/DJG27ZXi4Mc1eT4JBz3MklHTKiYcz5H38nya71jRpWmxenxY8nlNxIl5Gn@@iwskJOP73ilkLyaBBtBCV8MV9FMeDFBBh1D/g1W73MAeRSsEowqiBm4Kl4Qv)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
rõ ïvV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=cvUg73ZW&input=WzE1LDE4XQpbMiw0LDNd)

```
rõ ïvV     :Implicit input of arrays U=[start,end] and V=list
           > e.g., U=[15,18] V=[2,4,3]
r          :Reduce U by
 õ         :  Inclusive range
           > [15,16,17,18]
   ï V     :Cartesian product with V
           > [[15,2],[15,4],[15,3],[16,2],[16,4],[16,3],[17,2],[17,4],[17,3],[18,2],[18,4],[18,3]]
    v      :Reduce each pair by testing the divisibility of the first by the second
           > [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
           :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
           > 5
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python  54 bytes

```
lambda K,M,H:sum(n%l<1for n in range(K,M+1)for l in H)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I've edited your answer to fit the standard format, feel free to edit in any explanations, or links to online testing environments such as [Try it online!](https://tio.run)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 69 bytes

```
{s:Int,e:Int,l:List<Int>->(s..e).toList().sumBy{v->l.count{v%it==0}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVbbbttGEH3XV6yFFCVRhrbsyEnlyEWSJmiABHlIXgrDD2tpJW1DclnuUrYg6NvdMzNLWrKDFjUEmuQezuXM9bsLha3uj4/Vx6puw0RVLqxstVQL1yjXNmpuFrotggrGBzXT3vgBwDgMq8YY5Ws9w9XUutHBzNXCmmLuc/VtZXDf@EBo65VWja6WQAbdBGWrYJamEZg3M1fNGURgwRl6Iyho0oGOC93ExwoXQ2AWJ2JgdiNS1MyVpX4wioCFhflu0cn07B@EqNp5b28KWKtnwTU@HxD8XWPEHUZB6MzNjVq6YqFmK10UBjZOCLgKofaT42M6p@McFs2@mzugAMlhyfHfx6Nfz8fnY4L/4W5VqauNCrY0PlO6IcPNRpXg2NaF8b8pNuBP1/Lh0q5NFbkmd0oTYP1EHE/gTZoRHHTxg9LgjXxNxNf0gk4/6@8GtCzaahasq4TQxoS2qTyToEvXVsQPodk0BSf5qGrLG@LrxoRbA1MkgKQGOglOVvbWE8X0lSlMaargYQM/k0k5G3qnSwAnffDUVI3GFxxv3L26kEhN1dVppl5k6uyaPRiN1fRSjVSCUHTKSNdZyqfndHr65PSU7XwhmJeEOYGKf8OKvMZ4SvmpGnMsOJc77vzKtcVc6dnM1KiKW0cZZAPCxJkeU7ZjjWQiW3XT6M1@@jFxfi@iWYwHlR4RFlzQRQcntEjM1Rvv29JICGMxoTKM9@r1lFjcZ9kzzZ@jl8koU6OTTF3h/@l1esGMjh8jXp0Q5CVuIuR09OIAc3YC1PgEsKvRGe46SXjfswWSGm4Y3hUt02Yl0daWiuzo6EjScqPwzs3nlF7KrEEc8mVDbWeh167Jc6nG93c1iKRy7KJwa8OKy5yTTJKOy1yXN3OtWg9wcKR@bWIBd2XLBL1zFbQFtkkazqJxZSQUH8b24zhOkr3qa1uqtu7TGUooWNyzAmR49IpSS305tTQifK2L1qAffnAcRaNnq644MjhAVXdQL3AF7kuLtUtbIQlYGcd7btd2zkRVxaa3j4@igHwAilTduBkyImF3Jujs0AWP5G6g8EcyJ59weY1Xl6ma8lv5IM@BTfPg6DxJc@Tb243aiivq@SVDOyG5@BBPf7KomimqbKd2HLkPfctxsN7XBUJO/loaNlIerg24Z4@ld0gMxZP4zf/wZDvAawj7JJnw0MC7@GMuGOE8ZpXg@9TSNw45Q991@ZUDAfdUzTQBe/6rutkgv@@3fkKGGL4WD2Y8v0w8aHxM4nb9/LIQxrZrcDWdnux2u3uW@fsTdpAfXRMWSjLiSyzY51K6FVtZN0iKokqGyTNmLFPPwFamhr8M9kL2l7PVN/c1ALxMhjjF74ou18O0Aw5TKupn2zqJglgOfZ7uhulgt2fEQGoZldtz@JR1CWcJVIIpjgH2hlriazFiL2zfmg0c0vOuD6KSm5/94zVDsN1M73YOHnOhWzyoNwvuycw/mGFdyTGUe0Gu/muhOFB/IF56V9wkGPZOwwcaAlgKMDKIHvyi4oUtTIadqzqwNKP9ylbIOTvvTPoCw5tb600m0FjjygbSE0DblkO35rGB/MH4IiI/2cok6dFRjljZkAwR2R7XDWDGX51cI12RvckDQKayHI@eHsdRLeen152KbJjmpa6jQfQHI@O36Av8YqESEo6ZxUakEYpFBxvSR@TMUhdvmmVLBfi@Iy7pBQ7f6rlsrEfRn4NOsZ@uMbG@7AWAOi/mI6UsJUFHZZ8FD7tun1S0f5G4PokEydo8q/NcnjH4gpW2z8D9xi9LkfNRYtYZEJVTOycLKK47mBFmq8Q0jWsmSEvQo7GtppHcvuCJDwm7jKW4tvujH4SbtH5ZJKMx9gH@YXQ/jnmHeSU7A28FNPSfBD8C47@4tKXZwZAgQdg50qx7ovXiBxhaJ1LRQCxjo52bO2JL5hIeLXjqcuUg4leMveZIdPe9fNEQX6dMKw/tjfQx6kr3/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
#0×`%…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm18enJp/bnfxo6bGIkXDQzuLFI1AhLFm@aFt/5UNDk9PUH3UsOz///@GpgqGFgrRRjomOsaxXIYKhgYK0YY6RiCmhQGQba5jEctlbGCoYGoA4hoa65jGAgA) Nothing very special.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ṡ$vḊ
```

*-1 byte thanks to @lyxal*

[Try it online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwi4bmhJHbhuIoiLCIiLCIxXG44MDBcbls3LDhdIl0=)

Explanation:

```
ṡ     # Range from a to b
 $    # Swap (last input is now on top)
  vḊ  # For each in the range, test for divisibility with the last input
      # Deep flatten and sum with the d flag
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwi4bmhJHbhuIoiLCIiLCIxXG44MDBcbls3LDhdIl0=) for 4 bytes

Comment: @lyxal Nice, I suspected there would be a better way to get that last input

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻Σ÷ηζΣ÷⊖θζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYI7g0V8Mzr8QlsywzJVUjQ0ehSlNTRwFV1CU1uSg1NzWvJDVFo1ATrAQIrP//jzY2MNRRMDUwMNBRiDY0BjJjY//rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    η       Second input (End)
     ζ      Third input (List)
   ÷        Vectorised integer division
  Σ         Sum
         θ  First input (Start)
        ⊖   Decremented
          ζ Third input (List)
       ÷    Vectorised integer division
      Σ     Sum
 ⁻          Subtract
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
/.nm%LdeQ}.*PQ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X18vL1fVJyU1sFZPKyDQ4P9/Q1MdQwudaCMdEx3jWAA)

Takes input as `start, end, list`

Explanation:

```
         }        # Inclusive range
          .*      # Splat (list becomes list of arguments)
            PQ    # All but the last element of the input
                  # --> inclusive range from start to end
   m              # map each number of that
     L eQ         # to a map of each member of Q[-1] = list
    % d           # remainder modulo member (2, 4, 3 in example)
                  # --> List of lists of remainders
 .n               # flatten
/              0  # count zeroes
```

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1/VV6tWT8s10OD//2gjHQUTHQXjWC4NQ1MdBUMLTQA "Pyth – Try It Online") using multiple inputs and pfns

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (`-ap`), 33 bytes

```perl
for$i(<>..<>){$i%$_||$\++for@F}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glU8PGTk/Pxk6zWiVTVSW@pkYlRlsbKOHgVltb/f@/obGCKZexgSGXqYGBwb/8gpLM/Lzi/7qJBQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 54 bytes

```cs
(a,b,l)=>l.Where(x=>a%x<1).Count()+(++a>b?0:f(a,b,l));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxLC4JAFAXgvb/iboIRbzKjSZKPFlEQtHcRLVRGEmwCHzAq/XabqRZii3MXh@@evFnnTTmdOpGHpWhR53wU3YPXaVZx3cUI@kIB0URSzLAyo7iykzuvOZFRnK5kyEz78OxES0yLWFYaZ3u6K37YDCb1f72BhAhgZAjOKzCSumz5pRScFERVjKJU0jC@tFd0dBA2CO4Se0r72M/0oPUWwf/f9SlFGOb2g5mL3gK7VHGPKj9oP70B)

Recursive approach

Comment: It's recursive, but you don't define `f`. You should define it like this: `f=(a,b,l)=>...`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire If it is recursive, you have to include the whole function definition: `Func<int,int,IEnumerable<int>,int>f=(a,b,l)=>...`, since `f=(a,b,l)=>...` is not a valid expression (`f` does not exist yet). However, it would just be shorter to do `int f(int a,int b,IEnumerable<int>l)=>...`

Comment: if you take in `int[]` instead of `IEnumerable<int>` you can use `Length` instead of `Count()`, removing 1 byte

Answer (score 0):

## SimpleTemplate, 86 bytes

Yeah, kinda long, but it works!
Receives 2 numbers (in any order) and an array/string of 1-digit numbers (e.g.: `"243"`), passed to the `render()` method of the compiler.

```
{@fori fromargv.0 toargv.1}{@eachargv.2}{@ifi is multiple_}{@incR}{@/}{@/}{@/}{@echoR}
```

Displays the result or nothing, if none is

---

**Ungolfed**

```
{@set count 0}
{@for i from argv.0 to argv.1}
    {@each argv.2 as number}
        {@if i is multiple of number}
            {@inc by 1 count}
        {@/}
    {@/}
{@/}
{@echo count}
```

Should be mostly straightforward.

---

You can try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b26cd7f75e0c4676038573c4274180891a890895

Change line 986 to test the golfed and ungolfed versions, and line 988 to get the input.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
f[s_,e_,l_]:=(q=Quotient;Total[q[e,#]-q[s-1,#]&/@l])
```

This uses the simplification formula from @tsh

A less clever solution at 66 bytes but more directly following the OP:

```
f[s_,e_,l_]:=Total[Length@Intersection[Divisors@#,l]&/@Range[s,e]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 77 Bytes

Immediate window function that takes *start* from `[A1]`, *end* from `[B1]`, and *list* from column `C` (`[C:C]`). Output is directed to the immediate window.

`[C:C].SpecialCells(2)` is used to iterate `j` over only the cells in Column `C` which contain a value, as non-valued cells produce an error.

```vb
For i=[A1]To[B1]:For Each j In[C:C].SpecialCells(2):s=s-(i/j=i\j):Next j,i:?s
```